# prevent all characters and symbols if the first character is not # in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to prevent all characters and symbols if the first character is not #(hash) in jquery or javascript.

This is what I have tried, but `keyup` did not work.

```
<input data-role="tagsinput" type='text' placeholder="Enter search tags..." id="searchtag"> 

$("#searchtag input").keyup(function () {
     if ($(this).val().length >= 1){
        if ($(this).val() !== "#"){
            $(this).val('');
        }
     }
 });
```

Comment: `$("#searchtag input")` => `$("#searchtag")`

Comment: using $("#searchtag") I'm not getting any response with keyup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to prevent every event on key down, therefore the event will not register and you will not need to remove a character that has been added.

**NOTE:** The if statement can be simplified, written this way for clarity purposes.

Try to run the following snippet:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('searchtag');
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key === '#' && this.value.length === 0) {
    // Do nothing
  } else if (this.value.length > 0 && this.value[0] === '#') {
    // Do nothing
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchtag">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. The `input` should come in front or shouldn't come. Use either of it:

```js
$("input#searchtag").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
    if ($(this).val() !== "#") {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  }
});
```

```js
$("#searchtag").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
    if ($(this).val() !== "#") {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  }
});
```

When you give a space and `input`, it will try to look for the child `input` under the element with id `#searchtag`.